# Is there an SVN equivalent to the git prepare commit message hook

Tags: windows, svn, svn-hooks

I want to edit the incoming commit messages (adding branch name, or add a template that has some lines ignored etc). While I was searching I found that git has a prepare commit message hook that seems to do this but svn doesn't. Is there a way to do this in svn before the post commit?

Comment: See [this post](https://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2008-03/0690.shtml) on the mailing list.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk the post is about 9 years old and has a broken link. Here is the link that works: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#change-log-msg

Comment: Thanks for the links. Does that mean that I should be changing the log message in the post commit hook or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SVN you do not need to use hook scripts to add log message templates:

- With TortoiseSVN client, you can and should use [`tsvn:*` properties](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-tsvn-props).
- With vanilla svn.exe command-line client, use [`CMD_EDITOR`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externaleditors.html) environment variable to define which log message you want to call or make it determine the log message automatically based on the changes in your commit.
- [Use SVN hook scripts to validate, not modify](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.hooks.summary).
- Adjusting log messages for existing revisions in SVN is normally a one-line command. It is forbidden to modify the log messages, by default. An admin can always allow this to all or only certain users.

I guess that you already use TortoiseSVN client since the question is marked with [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) tag. TortoiseSVN supports several properties that should help you define the behavior of the client. They will help you implement commit policies including log message restrictions and templates:

- `tsvn:logminsize` defines minimum number of characters the log message of the incoming revision must contain.
- `tsvn:logtemplate` will help you define default log message template. There are 8 additional `tsvn:logtemplate` properties that you can use to add different templates for different types of commits.
- `tsvn:logsummary` will help you define regexp to grab a portion of commit message and display it as a summary when you view revision history log with TortoiseSVN.

See the [TortoiseSVN Project Properties](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html) chapter of the manual for complete list of properties and their purpose.

---

You must use git's `pre-commit` hooks to validate the log messages and add commit message templates. If you don't do this, the procedure to fix the mistakes in log messages requires you to use `git rebase` that can be non-trivial. There could be other ways to add log message policies, but in git's world you have to use hook scripts for this.

Don't forget that `svn commit` and `git commit` operations play different roles in common workflows with git or SVN. The whole idea and results of *svn commit* and *git commit* operations is different. Consequently, `*-commit` hooks have different goals in both systems:

- Running *git commit* in your local git repository is a local, client-side only operation. When you commit in git, you only make a local snapshot without contacting the blessed remote repository. In this case it should be perfectly fine to use local hooks to customize client's default behavior. Your local changes do not affect other git users unless you publish them by pushing or pulling. And this is the part of git's workflow that requires you to take maximum care about the log messages -- rewriting the commit's data (including the log message) will force your colleagues to put aside current tasks and begin manual repair of their local repos.
- But when you run *svn commit*, you contact the remote server to publish your local changes to the repository and make them available in form of new revision to other developers. Even if you made a mistake in log message when you commit to SVN, you can always adjust it yourself or ask a colleague who has such privilege. Simple and no harm caused.

Comment: I was using a template in TortoiseSVN which is the main reason that I wanted to change the log message in the first place. I had a section at the bottom of the template text that I wanted to ignore which gave instructions to users on commands that would get picked up by the post commit hook. for example If they included something line "RUN:Foo" in their message it would launch a Hudson job. I just didn't want the launch command or the command list to be included in the log messages committed

Comment: I commented too quickly I will try they tsvn:logsummary that you mentioned tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

In the rare places where it *may* be possible to change an incoming transaction with Subversion, it is not recommended or supported to do so.